# Why my reduce() function is not unable to find out correct maxGrade?

Tags: javascript, string, reduce

I'm trying to find out the correct Max grade from a given numbers list.
So, when i use this `highAndLow("4 5 29 54 4 0 -214 542 -64 1 -3 6 -6")` the function  gives me `6` as `maxGrade` but it should be `542`.

Please, check the code and explain the problem.

```js
function highAndLow(numbers) {
  var num = numbers.split(" ");

  var maxGrade = num.reduce((accum, currVal) => {
    if (accum > currVal) return accum;
    return currVal;

  });
  console.log(maxGrade);
  console.log(num);
}

highAndLow("4 5 29 54 4 0 -214 542 -64 1 -3 6 -6")
```

Comment: You are comparing strings. Convert them to numbers before reduce: `numbers.split(" ").map(Number)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `split()` to convert the string to an array, you actually have an `array of strings`

You can use `Array.map(Number)` to convert strings into number

The string value `"6"` is greater than the string value `"542"`

```js
function highAndLow(numbers) {
  var num = numbers.split(" ").map(Number);

  var maxGrade = num.reduce((accum, currVal) => {
    if (accum > currVal) return accum;
    return currVal;
  });
  console.log(maxGrade);
  console.log(num);
}

highAndLow("4 5 29 54 4 0 -214 542 -64 1 -3 6 -6")
```

Answer (score 2):

You could split the string and spread the values for getting a max value.

[`Math.max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) converts the parameters as to numbers.

```js
function highAndLow(numbers) {
    return Math.max(...numbers.split(" "));
}

console.log(highAndLow("4 5 29 54 4 0 -214 542 -64 1 -3 6 -6"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert to number first.

```
var num = numbers.split(" ").map(x => Number(x));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use max function:

```js
function highAndLow(numbers) {
  var num = numbers.split(" ");

  var maxGrade = num.reduce((accum, currVal) => Math.max(accum, currVal));
  console.log(maxGrade);
  console.log(num);
}

highAndLow("4 5 29 54 4 0 -214 542 -64 1 -3 6 -6")
```